# VBA recognizing more than one cell is highlighted

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following VBA script:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("calendar")) Is Nothing Then
       [selectedCell1] = ActiveCell.Value

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    End If
End Sub
```

Currently, It recognizes only one cell is highlighted and returns it into the specific cell named selectedCell1.

This is my example:
[image]

If I select the cell N25 which contains the date "03/08/2017" it returns "03/08/2017" into another sheet cell named "selectedCell1".

But what I would like it to do, is realize I've selected the entire week, and then return that entire week range in cell "selectedCell1". See: 
[image]

And then return 01/08/2017 - 05/08/2017 (that entire range) in cell "selecetedCell1".

Not sure how to adjust this VBA script. Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `[selectedCell1].Resize(Target.Rows.Count, Target.Columns.Count) = Target.Value`  Don't use ActiveCell :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("calendar")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
            [selectedCell1] = Target.Value
        Else
            [selectedCell1] = Format(Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Target), "dd/mm/yyyy") & " - " & Format(Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Target), "dd/mm/yyyy")
        End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```